# Do I need another index besides this one in SQLLite?

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have a unique index set up across three columns in SQLLite, and am wondering if I need any other indexes, as retrieving results from the following query sometimes takes almost 10 sec (database size is only about 25,000 rows):

```
SELECT * FROM books 
WHERE (Author="Roger Davies" COLLATE NOCASE AND 
Title>="My Best Days" COLLATE NOCASE AND 
CatID>"rtYY91" COLLATE NOCASE ) 

OR Author > "Roger Davies" COLLATE NOCASE  

ORDER BY Author COLLATE NOCASE ASC, 
Title COLLATE NOCASE ASC, 
CatID COLLATE NOCASE ASC LIMIT 10
```

The index is:
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX booksIndex ON books ( CatID, Author, Title )

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index is not used at all.
(You could have noticed this with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).)

To make it possible to use the index for this query, add COLLATE NOCASE to the columns in the [index definition](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html).

However, the columns in an index can be used only beginning with the leftmost index column, and an inequality comparison (like >=) can be used only in *one* column if an index, and prevents any further index columns from being used.

So the possible comparisons that could be optimized by this particular index are:

- `CatID = x`; or
- `CatID > x`; or
- `CatID = x AND Author = y`; or
- `CatID = x AND Author > y`; or
- `CatID = x AND Author = y AND Title = z`; or
- `CatID = x AND Author = y AND Title > z`.

(However, the optimizer is able to reorder the comparisons in the WHERE clause to match this.)

If you want to optimize a query that is sorted first by the author, you need an index with that as the first column.

If you can have different queries with different sort orders, you need multiple indexes.
In that case, it might be a better idea to have only one-column indexes so that the number of indexes does not get out of hand.

Comment: Thank you CL. So just set up a single index on each column that will possible be searched on, right? If I run a CREATE INDEX on a column that already has that index, will SQLLIte gracefully ignore it? I need to retrofit the indexes to user's databases. Also, I need to keep the original index so they three columns remain unique, but I'll probably set up single indexes on them too. If this is the case, would there be any need for me to COLLATE NOCASE the original unique index, or just do that on the indexes?

Comment: SQLite will not prevent you from creating duplicate indexes. You need COLLATE NOCASE on the original unique index if you want to prevent case-insensitive duplicates.

Comment: Can COLLATE NOCASE be retrofitted to an existing index, or is it best to drop and recreate the index? Last question (thank you CL) - when applying an index to a column that is already populated with data, will the index include what's already there, or do you need to tell SQLLite to flush?

Comment: OK - I'm thinking my best move is to create a new table with the correct collation (COLLATE NOCASE) on the columns, and copy the data from the old table. Rookie question - will the data I'm copying from a column that is not COLLATE NOCASE successfully take on NOCASE collation when copied to the new table's COLLATE NOCASE column, or is there some things I need to consider when copying data from one collation to another?

Comment: A collation is not a property of the data but of some operation on the data. When a table column is declared as COLLATE NOCASE, comparisons of values in this column will use COLLATE NOCASE by default.

Comment: Ahhh - so instead of 'WHERE Author="Roger Davies" COLLATE NOCASE' I can just say 'WHERE Author="Roger Davies"' - right? But I would still need to stipulate 'SORT BY Auther COLLATE NOCASE' if I want the results to be unaffected by case, yeah?

Comment: The comparison `Author=x` uses the collation of that column by default. The `ORDER BY Author` uses the collation of that column by default.

Comment: CL- I'm misunderstanding- my queries are still ignoring the indexes. Must the actual table columns be set up COLLATE NOCASE too (when the table's created), or just the index? Index: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx ON table1 (Author,Title,hID COLLATE NOCASE). Queries that ignore it: SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Author COLLATE NOCASE ASC,Title COLLATE NOCASE ASC,hID COLLATE NOCASE ASC LIMIT 100. SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Author, Title, hID LIMIT 100. In another post re PK errors when copying tables to set up columns NO CASE, someone said 'why make columns NOCASE- just do that to the index'.

Comment: An index has the same collation as the column by default, and to be useful, must use the same collation that is actually used in the comparison/sorting. If an index has any collation but `BINARY`, to be useful for *both* searching and sorting in the same query, it must be `UNIQUE`.

Comment: So yes? I need to make the column collation the same as what I want the index to be - in this case both COLLATE NOCASE? So the other post telling me 'just make the index COLLATE NOCASE' when the column is not COLLATE NOCASE is incorrect?

Comment: You can make the index NOCASE when the column isn't, but then you must also specify NOCASE every time you're doing a comparison or sorting for it to be used.

Comment: OK - it still wasn't using the index, and then I realised my index code was CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx ON table1 (Author,Title,hID COLLATE NOCASE) instead of CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx ON table1 (Author COLLATE NOCASE,Title COLLATE NOCASE,hID COLLATE NOCASE). It's accessing the index now. Now I'll test to see if it does so when using > or < in queries. THANK YOU CL!

Comment: Yes - it does, even if the query also contains %LIKE% statements. Wahooo! Thanks again CL.

Comment: Just experimenting having individual indexes for each column as opposed to indexes over three columns, and running the same queries. They no longer utilize any index. Is this to be expected, or do I need to recode the indexes some way? I ask, as I allow ordering to start with any of the 8 columns, and then alway followed by author, title, hID. It would be ideal to have 8 single column indexes in total, rather than 8 such as eg (DateAdded, Author, Title, hID), and then another (Language, Author, Title, hID).

Comment: Read [this](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) and [this](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

Comment: Cheers CL. So I really need covering indexes for each scenario, which in this case is at least 8 eg scenario 1: (DateAdded, Author, Title, hID), scenario 2: (Language, Author, Title, hID) etc. Makes sense.

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up creating 18 indexes to cover the 18 different ways of ordering. It takes quite a while to make updates to bulk rows (updating 30 000 rows takes about 4 minutes), as all the indexes have to be updated, but searching is VERY fast, and updating smaller amounts of data is too. Just wanted to know - if ALL of the indexes are four columns, and all have the last three columns in common eg (colX, col2, col3, col4) - all have col2, col3, col4 in common - that there is definitely no way to combine a single 3 column common index with a variable column index to cover each query? Thanks!

Comment: At most one index per table per query; that's the rule.

Comment: Cheers for your help CL